# Vectorizing a complex nested for loop in R (running models on different subsets of a data set, subsetting the data differently for each loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, nested-loops, bayesian

This is my first time posting so hopefully I manage to get my question across in a clear and concise manner.

I am running a cross-validation experiment which involves training a model on a subset of a data set and then validating it against the rest of the data set. This is done by randomly subsetting the data into "folds" and then running the model for each fold. This is then replicated in order to produce standard errors. This is the code I have written in R:

```
reps = 10
folds = 10
rep.Res<-list()

for(i in 1:reps){
  #i=1
  phen2<-phen
  phen2$fold<-sample(1:folds,nrow(phen),replace=T)

  fold.Res<-list()

  for(j in 1:folds){
    #j=1

    print(paste(i," ",j))

    phen3<-phen2
    phen3[which(phen3$fold==j),2]<-NA

    ETA<-list(list(X = geno_centred, model = 'BayesA'))

    model <- BGLR(y = phen3[,2], ETA = ETA, nIter = 20000, 
                  burnIn = 1500,  thin=10) 

    model.output<-data.frame(ID = phen3[which(phen2$fold == j), 1],
                             PBV = as.numeric(model$yHat[which(phen2$fold == j)]),
                             phen = phen2[which(phen2$fold == j), 2], rep = i, fold = j)


fold.Res[[j]]<-model.output


  }

  rep.Res[[i]]<-do.call(rbind,fold.Res)


}
```

"phen" is a data frame with a a column of IDs and a column of values. For each replicate, each sample is assigned to a fold randomly. Then, for each fold individuals in the fold are given an NA value, i.e. excluded from the model.

The model is run using the Bayesian Generalised Linear Regression (BGLR) package. Unfortunately, I can't really give a reproducible example. X is a scaled centred genotype matrix of -1's, 0's and 1's (not critical for my problem here). The output of the model is then written out for each fold, and then finally for each replicate.

My question is, is it possible to vectorize these loops? Using 10 folds and 10 reps means that the model runs 100 time, at 20 000 MCMC iterations each time. This causes the system to slow down significantly before it's even half done. I know that there are many possible approaches using basic R or packages in the tidyverse suite, but I am really a bit lost with such a complex loop. I can imagine that I would try to write at least one of the loops into a function enclosing the other loop but I'm not even sure how that would work...

Again, first time posting so please let me know if I need to add anything to my question! Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion: consider posting your question over at the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They might be more open to offering broad performance improvements. Also, you might find some helpful info in the free book [*R Inferno*](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-r-inferno-revised/).

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I tried to post it there; hopefully I'll get a response.